# How to use InitialContext database info in a Java SE project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jdbc

This may be a somewhat strange question, but I'm not sure how to do this another way. Basically, I am sharing connection code between two maven projects. One is a Maven Web application and the other is a regular Maven project.

To set up the database connection context, I'm using META_INF/context.xml in the Maven web application.

However, the regular Maven project doesn't use this file, so when the code to get the data source is run:

```
Context envCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
dbPool = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/MyAppUCP");
```

of course a NamingException is thrown. How can I reuse this method of getting the database connection with the regular Maven java application? Copying the META_INF/ directory into the project doesn't work.

Comment: Show your jdbc resource, maybe you just haven't named it correctly.

Comment: It works just fine in the Maven web application. That isn't the issue. The problem is that I want to be able to use the envCtx.lookup("jdbc/MyAppUCP") in the regular maven project.

Answer (score 1):

The InitialContext with default constructor works only in managed environment (j2EE container). If you need to lookup for JNDI from a Java SE process, you need to pass in a property object as parameter to the overloaded constructor.

Each app/webserver has it's own set of properties that needs to be set in the property object. Refer to app server's documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html).

Again, there would be security constraint on looking up for JNDI entries from external process.